# Show Multiple Rows in one row in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show multiple row in one row based on a MemberID. See the table below:

MemberID .... MemberName ........... ProjectID ....... Taka

1 .................. Repon Hossain .............. 5 ...............500/-
1 .................. Repon Hossain .............. 6 ...............600/-
1 .................. Repon Hossain .............. 7 ...............800/-
2 .................. Rony Ahmed ................. 5 ...............700/-
2 .................. Rony Ahmed ................. 6 ...............600/-
2 .................. Rony Ahmed ................. 8 ...........10,000/-
3 .................. Shahinur Rahman ......... 6 ...........12,000/-
3 .................. Shahinur Rahman ......... 7 ...........1,000/-
3 .................. Shahinur Rahman ......... 8 ...........50,000/-

and I want show above rows in one row based on a MemberID using crystal report. I don't want to change the sql query.

MemberID ... Member Name ..... Daily Savings ...... Weekly Savings ......... DPS ....... FDR 
 1 ................. Repon Hossain .......... 500/- .......................600/-  .................800/- ....... 0/- 

 2 ................. Rony Ahmed .............. 700/- .......................600/- ...................0 ..........10,000/-

 3 ................. Shahinu Rahman ......... 0 .........................1200/- ................ 1000/- ....50,000/-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- Daily Savings are values for ProjectID 5;
- Weekly Savings are values for ProjectID 6;
- DPS are values for ProjectID 7;
- FDR are values for ProjectID 8;

- set up formulas for each of Daily Savings, Weekly Savings, DPS and FDR, similar to:

```
if {MyTable.ProjectID}=5 then {MyTable.Taka} else 0
```

(with appropriate values of ProjectID for each formula.)

Group the report on MemberID, hide the detail and group header rows, and add the member ID and member name fields, and the **sums** of each of the new formulas, to the group footer.

Comment: Correct balance show for projectid 6 filed but not work for other project id. Other project ID balance is 0.00 .

Comment: I used the sums field to the details section (the section is hide) and insert the summery field for MemberID group. It is right now.